# recyclerview :onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

In my app,i use recyclerview to refresh my view.But when i use the method:notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload),payload is not null,the method:onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position, List payloads) not working.please tell me why?thanks.

Network request success after calling method：

```
for (int i=0; i<mDatas.size(); i++) {
                Device d = mDatas.get(i);
                if (modelId.equals(d.getModelId())) {
                    if (getHeaderView() != null) {
                        adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(i + 1, 1,payload);
                    } else {
                        adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(i, 1,payload);
                    }
                }
            }
```

my adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
    if (payloads.isEmpty()) {
        onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    } else {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER || viewType == TYPE_FOOTER) return;
        final int pos = getRealPosition(holder);
        final T data = mDatas.get(pos);
        onBind(holder, pos, data, payloads);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your adaptor code and activity where you are passing data

Comment: Network request success after calling method：for (int i=0; i<mDatas.size(); i++) {
     Device d = mDatas.get(i);
     if (device.getId().equals(d.getId())) {
      mDatas.set(i, device);
      if (getHeaderView() != null) {
       adapter.notifyItemChanged(i + 1, payload);
      } else {
       adapter.notifyItemChanged(i, payload);
      }
     }
    }
note:if payload is not null,that method is working

Comment: my adapter:public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
  if (payloads.isEmpty()) {
   onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
  } else {
   int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
   if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER || viewType == TYPE_FOOTER) return;
   final int pos = getRealPosition(holder);
   final T data = mDatas.get(pos);
   onBind(holder, pos, data, payloads);
  }
 }

Comment: Can you please edit your question and paste this code inside for better readability ??

Comment: Sorry, I have to re edit the problem

Comment: onBindViewHolder() method has only two parameters, 1st is Viewholder object and 2nd is position for corresponding view, there is no 3rd parameter, Pass data in your adapter by creating constructor in your adapter and pass your List<Object> payloads....

Comment: @Bhavnik there are two `onBindViewHolder()` methods, there is an overload taking three parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think thie problem is caused by "android:fitsSystemWindows="true"",but the reason I don't konw.who can tell me why.